# Is it possible to use sort() on multiple fields in Doctrine 2 ODM?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, symfony1, doctrine-orm, odm

I am doing a query on a result document in my doctrine *mongodb* *odm*. There are two indexed fields in the document which I would like to use in sort. I have written something like:

```
$results = $this->createQueryBuilder('Document\Score')
            ->sort('finalScore', 'desc')
            ->sort('date', 'desc')
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute();
```

Here the second `sort()` function overrides the first one and the designated result is never found.

Thanks in advance for the nice help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('Document\Score');
$qb->sort(array(
    'finalScore' => 'desc',
    'date'       => 'desc',
));
$results = $qb->getQuery()->execute();
```

Comment: OK! I am trying this out! Thanks for prompt reply! I will let you know.